# Trying to figure out how to use PIVOT in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `Work` with two columns - `Name` and `Status`:

```
SELECT Name,Status FROM Work

--------+----------
Name    |Status
--------+----------
MyBJE   |2
MyBJE_2 |9
MyBJE   |8
MyBJE_2 |9
MyBJE   |7
MyBJE_2 |9
MyBJE   |2
MyBJE   |8
MyBJE_2 |3
MyBJE   |8
MyBJE   |8
MyBJE_2 |1
MyBJE_2 |8
MyBJE   |4
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a query, which would return the following result from the aforementioned data:

```
--------+-------+-------+-------
Name    |COUNT_2|COUNT_3|COUNT_4
--------+-------+-------+-------
MyBJE   |2      |0      |1
MyBJE_2 |0      |1      |0
```

The expected semantics is as follows:

1. Ignore all the entries with the Status other than 2, 3 or 4
2. For each given Name count the occurrences of 2, 3 and 4 and display the total count in a dedicated column.
3. If a Name does not have any entry with the Status of 2, 3 or 4 make sure this Name **does appear** in the result with 0 in every COUNT_X column.

Here is what I did so far (the data is taken from a real database, not the example from above).

```
SELECT Name, Status, COUNT(1)
FROM (SELECT Name, (CASE when Status IN (2,3,4) then Status else 0 end) as Status FROM Work) x
GROUP BY Name, Status

--------+------+----------------
Name    |Status|(No column name)
--------+------+----------------
MyBJE_2 |0     |262
MyBJE_2 |2     |1033
MyBJE   |0     |2496
```

Now I know I am supposed to use the PIVOT statement, but I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select   name,
         sum(case when status=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Count_2,
         sum(case when status=3 then 1 else 0 end) as Count_3,
         sum(case when status=4 then 1 else 0 end) as Count_4
from     work
group by name
```

Comment: So, simple. And I thought I needed a PIVOT... Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name,sum(Case when Status=2 then 1 Else 0 End) Count_2,sum(Case when Status=3 then 1 Else 0 End) Count_3,
sum(Case when Status=4 then 1 Else 0 End) Count_3
From tableName
where Status in(2,3,4)
Group By Name
```